# new column with value = col a / col b

Tags: sql, select, divide

I'd like to add a new column that divides the values of two `existing columns` and returns the result as a `percentage` to an existing `SQL query` .

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Why add it as a column? It makes more sense just to calculate it, like `select a,b, (a / b) as ratio from Foo;`

Comment: @DavidLively, there are many times when doing this calculation repeately in select statements is a far worse idea than persisting the column in the database with the calculation.

Comment: @HLGEM I understand the potential performance impact, but this should only be an issue when returning *very* large result sets, probably for reporting rather than UI (unless you're presenting the user with a few million rows in a table, or generating a visualization that can effectively present such large amounts of information.)

Comment: Also, in the case that you *really* need to cache the result of the division, just calculate it on insert and update (via triggers assuming you're using a real database).

Answer (score 3):

SQL supports arithmetic operations:

```
SELECT a, b, 100.0 * a / b AS percentage
FROM   my_table
WHERE  (some condition)
```

EDIT:
As noted in the comments, if `b` is zero, we cannot divide `a` by `b`. This edge case should be handled explicitly. In the following example I return `null` for this case, but any other treatment that makes sense in your real-world issue's context would do:

```
SELECT a, b, CASE WHEN b = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 100.0 * a / b END AS percentage
FROM   my_table
WHERE  (some condition)
```

Comment: if b ever can be 0 you should do "case when b = 0 then 0 else a / b * 100 end"

Comment: Might use `(100.0 * a) / b` to ensure that you're using floating-point division.

Comment: This works, but I'm getting an error: "divisor is equal to zero." Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are times when it makes sense to have this as a persisted calculation rather than calculate millions of records on the fly.

If you want to do this in the table defintion, you use a persisted calculated column. The example below handles the problem of nulls in the demonimator and it also handles the problem of integer math.

```
alter table mytable
add [Result] AS (ColA*1.00/NULLIF(ColB,0)) Persisted
```

Calcualted columns are one of the most underused features of a database. It pays to know about them . More complicated scenarios for calculation might need to be handled in a trigger.